# Google Scripts: Error when sendEmail to bcc list

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to send an email to a distribution list housed in a google spreadsheet. I am using a test sheet with only 3 email addresses on the list before I move this into a live environment. I'd like it to send to me, and bcc everyone on the list. The script works fine if I put the list of email addresses in the recipient spot of sendEmail, but not when I try to move the email addresses to the bcc spot using the bcc advanced argument of sendEmail. In that case I get the following error:

Error encountered: Invalid email: [L;@130cab11

In this error the "130cab11" portion changes everytime I run the script. The only consistent part of the script is "Error encountered: Invalid email: [L; ..."

The relevant portion of my script is below:

```
// Retrieve data for the Email that will be sent///
   var email_column = ss.getSheetByName(sendtosheet)
   var lastrow = email_column.getLastRow()
   var get_email_data = email_column.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,1).getValues()
   var emailTemplate = ss.getSheetByName("Email Templates").getRange("B1").getValue()
   var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
      Logger.log(aliases)

//Format the email
   var advancedArgs = {bcc:get_email_data,from: aliases[0]}
   var Self = "MyEmail@mycompany.com"
   var subject = "INVITE: Upcoming Focus Group Session";
   var message = emailTemplate

//Send the email
   GmailApp.sendEmail(Self, subject, message, advancedArgs)
```

This code works without error if I send the email without using the bcc argument and have the sendEmail code structured like this:

```
//Send the email
   GmailApp.sendEmail(get_email_data, subject, message, {from: aliases[0]})
```

I have searched stackoverflow and google scripts manuals and everywhere else I can think of so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the bcc list as a string.

```
var get_email_data = email_column.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,1).getValues()
```

After the above statement, `get_email_data` contains a two-dimensional array of objects, the content of the indicated range. That's why that error message complains about `[L;...` - it's got an array when it wanted a string, but is blindly treating it as a string and finding it difficult.

Before you can do this:

```
 var advancedArgs = {bcc:get_email_data,from: aliases[0]}
```

... you need to join the content of your array into a string containing a comma-separated list of substrings. Luckily, the Array method `.toString()` will do that, even for this two-dimensional array.

```
var get_email_data = email_column.getRange(2,2,lastrow-1,1).getValues()
                                 .toString();
```